# Ошибка Property 'driverClassName' must not be empty в спринг MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

[image: Ошибка]

```
класс DBConfig `
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "testgroup.filmography")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:db.properties")
public class DbConfig {


    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("db.driver"));
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("db.url"));
        driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("db.username"));
        driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("db.password"));
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean getEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean =
                new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(environment.getProperty("db.entitymanager.packages.to.scan"));

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getProperty("db.hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getProperty("db.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));

        localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(properties);
        return localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager getJpaTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(getEntityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }
}`
```

pom.xml

4.0.0

```
<groupId>testgroup</groupId>
<artifactId>filmography</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring5</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.17.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>




</dependencies>

<build>
        <plugins>
                <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.8.0</version>
                        <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        </configuration>
                </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

db.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1?serverTimezone=Europe/Minsk&useSSL=false

jdbc.username=root

jdbc.password=simonova12

#Hibernate

db.entitymanager.packages.to.scan=filmography.model

db.hibernate.show_sql=true

db.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```

service

```
    @Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{


    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;




    @Transactional
    public List<User> allUsers() {
        return userDAO.allUsers();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void add(User user) {
        userDAO.add(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void delete(int id) {
        userDAO.delete(id);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void edit(User user) {
        userDAO.edit(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public User getById(int id) {
        return userDAO.getById(id);
    }
}
```

DAO

```
    @Repository
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {


    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;




    public List<User> allUsers() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("from User").getResultList();
    }


    public void add(User user) {
        entityManager.persist(user);
    }


    public void edit(User user)
    {
        entityManager.merge(user);
    }


    public User getById(int id) {
        return entityManager.find(User.class, id);
    }

    public void delete(int id) {
        entityManager.remove(getById(id));
    }
}
```

как думаете, в чем может быть проблема, куда копать ?

UPDATE полный стактрейс

```
Root Cause 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getEntityManagerFactoryBean' defined in class path resource [testgroup/filmography/config/DbConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'getEntityManagerFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getDataSource' defined in class path resource [testgroup/filmography/config/DbConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'getDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'driverClassName' must not be empty
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:117

org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Factory method 'getEntityManagerFactoryBean' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getDataSource' defined in class path resource [testgroup/filmography/config/DbConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'getDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'driverClassName' must not be empty
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)

Root Cause 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getDataSource' defined in class path resource [testgroup/filmography/config/DbConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'getDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'driverClassName' must not be empty
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:645)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)

org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'getDataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'driverClassName' must not be empty
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:475)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
```

Comment: Вы текст ошибки читали? там же написано где и что за проблема. На скрине вы это как раз и обрезали.

Comment: Добавил полный стактрэйс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже, что проблема в том, что в `db.properties` указаны одни имена для параметров конфигурации БД, а в `DbConfig`  в собственно конфигурации `DataSource` используются другие ну и имена параметров с префиксами `db.` попросту не находятся:

Сравните `db.properties`

```
jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test1?serverTimezone=Europe/Minsk&useSSL=false
jdbc.username=root
jdbc.password=simonova12
```

с `DbConfig`:

```
driverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getProperty("db.driver"));
driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty("db.url"));
driverManagerDataSource.setUsername(environment.getProperty("db.username"));
driverManagerDataSource.setPassword(environment.getProperty("db.password"));
```

Чтобы исправить используйте одинаковые имена параметров.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Теперь стыдно, что сам не заметил )